# How to insert a PHP code which has HTML tag inside the Javascript

Tags: javascript, php, html

I want to add a PHP script which has HTML tags, inside a javascript. Below you can see the code I tried. But It's not working and stating that there is an error

```js
<script type='text/javascript'>
//<![CDATA[
 $(document).ready(function() {
  var currentItem = 11;
  $('#addnew').click(function(){
   currentItem++;
   $('#items').val(currentItem);
var strToAdd = '<tr><td><select class="form-control select2" name="product'+currentItem+'" id="product'+currentItem+'" style="width: 100%">'+
                <?php foreach ($productData as $product) { echo "<option value='" . $product->product_id . "'>" . $product->product_name . "</option>"; }?>+
                '</select> </td><td><input class="form-control" name="quantity'+currentItem+'" id ="quantity'+currentItem+'"type="text" /></td> 
                <td><input class="form-control"  name="freeIssue'+currentItem+'" id="freeIssue'+currentItem+'" type="text" /></td>
                 <td align="center"><button  class="btn btn-danger" name="close" id="close" onclick="SomeDeleteRowFunction(this)"><i class="fa fa-close"></i></button></td></tr>';



   $('#data').append(strToAdd);

  });

  $('#remove').on("click", function(){
    $('#data tr:last').remove();
})

 });

//]]>
</script>
```

This is the error I get:

[image]

Comment: You can view your rendered source code by pressing `Ctrl+u` what can you see in that in ur javascript ?

Comment: Your quotes are off. If you echo a string from PHP, you need to wrap the result in `'`, like this: `'<?php .... ?>'` or it will print HTML directly into the javascript block and the browser will try and parse the html as js.

Comment: I would always suggest that you generate content before echo it like this, its unnecessary complex and at this level is irrelevant for the page speed. So use a extra variable. To the main question, you should check your quotation there are a few problem due the fact that you closed the string syntax and open it again to late. So Javascript tries to evaluate part of the String which causes the Error you are seeing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to put an extra `'` after `echo "` otherwise you do not get the desired javascript string like `'<option... >'` but you get an `<option... >` which means nothing in a js code.

```
 echo "'<option value='" . $product->product_id . "'>'"
```